# XCode won't run my application on a device/simulator anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am kind of stuck with my XCode problem. First of all: I have a project that contains 5 different targets. Now something went wrong (I can't remember changing anything related to project settings).

If I want to run any target on device or simulator the build succeeds but then nothing happens. Neither the app is started in simulator nor on a device. So I checked the Scheme (-> "Edit scheme") and I could not select my app in the Executable menu. I think I can remember that the .app file was selected there before (as it is if i create any new project). Does anyone know why I can't select anything there?

What I am curious about, is the fact that choosing "Other" in the Executable menu brings me to my DerivedData directory that indeed contains the *.app file resulting from the build. That leads me to my next problem.

If I select this *.app file explicitly and try to run the app XCode gives me the error " does not have an architecture that  can execute." But I checked my settings many times and I am definitly using $(ARCHS_STANDARD) in every target.

I am a little bit lost here ... does anyone has a hint, what could have messed up my project and how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of targets do you have? Do you have an app target defined? Is it configured to compile for Run in the build section of your Debug scheme (or whatever scheme your using for simulator)? Your architecture is properly set for *that* target and not just the project? What does your valid architectures look like for that target? Finally...did you recently update Xcode, and do you use Cocoapods?

Comment: Yes my targets seem to be configured correctly. But I gave the problem another thought and compared the project.pbxproj to an older (working) version and I found out that the *.app files are missing in the FileReference section and that the targets do not have the productReference set to one of the *.app files. Does anyone know how to fix this issue via XCode. Because I've tried to fix it by copying the the relevant parts from the older project file into the corrupt one. But this lead to the problem, that the Project couldn't even be opened in XCode anymore.

Comment: There is an odd scenario, probably with Macs that have been running for weeks or months, where the Mac essentially runs out of process handles or something like that.  Rebooting the box fixes it up.

Answer (score 1):

Might not work, but I've found a lot of bugs in xcode which simply require quitting it, and reopening.

You could also try clearing out the DerivedData directory.  Do a full clean build (hold down option key when selecting clean build).

And lastly, reset the simulator via the menu iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I changed the name of my App on one development machine and then tried to work on it a few months later on another machine. I fixed it by deleting the old scheme and Autocreating the new scheme. The settings are under Product - Scheme - Manage Schemes.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved the problem by myself. I was on the right track before. I did compare the project.pbxproj file again using FileMerge. I merged all lines related to an *.app file from the working version into my corrupt project file. After that my project was fixed. The *.app files showed up under the "Product" group in XCode and I could run the application on simulator/devices again. It seems that I forgot something while I was merging the files via copy & paste. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Rather than cleaning out the DerivedData directory from Xcode, have you tried the "old fashioned" way from Finder? Try quitting Xcode, nuking `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache` from Finder, and restarting Xcode.